# reduce django db calls

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I noticed that my django code calls my database very often with the exact same queries.

I understand that a db hit is made when I actually need the data to display on a page or to evaluate. However, my template code looks like this:

template:

```
{% if item.listing %}
        {{ item.name }} text <strong>{{ item.listing|lowestprice }}</strong>  more text
{% else %}
        {{ item.name }} even more text
{% endif %}
     ....
{% for listed_item in item.listing %}
     ....
{% endfor %}
```

custom filter:

```
def lowestprice(value):
   try:
      val = unicode(value[0].price) + unicode(value[0].symbol)
      return val
   except:
      return "not available"
```

This code hits my db three times. First on template `{% if .. %}` second on my custom filter, third on the `{% for %}` loop.

listing is a method of my models class which is returning a raw SQL queryset with some very expensive joins.

```
def listing(self):
    return Universe.objects.raw("ONE HELL OF A QUERY")
```

How can I reduce my code to hit the db only once?

Edit: Using `with` works, but is it possible to avoid db hits on custom filters?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `with` to do the expensive query once and store it the context.

```
{% with item.listing as item_listing %}
   {% if item_listing %} ... {% endif %} ... etc ...
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Is `with` limited to use only in one `block` ?